# Please create some new tags: [smart-pointer] and [c++-cli]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

I feel that these tags would

1. be generally useful on this site
2. apply to [my question here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1695/scoped-ptr-for-c-cli-ensure-managed-object-properly-frees-owned-native-object)

Would someone please be so kind as to add them, or explain why they're bad?

[This question by another user](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4009/which-is-the-better-way-to-return-a-new-instance-of-a-boost-intrusive-ptr) would probably also benefit from a [smart-pointer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smart-pointer) tag.

Answer (score 6):

They seem like reasonable tags to me, so I added them to your question for you.